# how to structure angular app when using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how to structure parts of my angular.js app when using angular-ui-router. I have followed [this article](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/using-nested-states-angularjs-ui-router/) and created a demo app.

My app has a home page with a top navbar. and a view (say view1) which has a left vertical navbar. and a right pane in which I'll show the details of the item selected in the left navbar.

Currently I have put the top navbar in a template and loading it using `ng-include` in `header` tag. After that I have a `ui-view`.

What I need to know is, am I doing it correctly? I have Googled a lot and tried to understand the functionalities of `ui-router` and its `ui-view`s. But just need to be sure if I'm following the standard way.

There's not any specific piece of code that I could show so not posting any. Please provide some information on the same or if any resources that explain these concepts in detail.

Comment: John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you had already done some research on ui-router. So I just recommend one tutorial that I found that it was useful for me when I war trying to learn ui-route. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router The website has a lot of nice tutorial for angular, enjoy.

Comment: Wow! That video really helped. It's clear in my head now... Thanks

Comment: Here's another more in depth video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqJRoh8MnBo.  Worth watching when you have an hour.